# Symfony 4 PHPunit no database selected

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I try to do some tests with Symfony 4 and phpunit 6, but i have an error message :

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected" at
>   /var/www/userDemo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   line 108 F
>   2 / 2 (100%)

```html
namespace App\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class RegistrationControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

        $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertSame(0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Hello World")')->count());
    }

    public function testCheckPassword(){
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request(
            'GET',
            '/register'
        );

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('S\'inscrire')->form();

        $form['user[email]'] = 'toto@email.com';
        $form['user[username]'] = 'usernametest';
        $form['user[fullName]'] = 'John Doe';
        $form['user[password][first]'] = 'pass1';
        $form['user[password][second]'] = 'pass2';

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

        //echo $client->getResponse()->getContent();


        $this->assertEquals(1,
            $crawler->filter('li:contains("This value is not valid.")')->count()
        );


    }

}
```

My env file :

> APP_ENV=dev
>   APP_SECRET=XXXX
>   DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/userdemo

This application work well in dev environnement

Thank you !

[EDIT]
Just add in phpunit.xml.dist

```html
<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/userDemo" />
```

Thank you to @dbrumann

Comment: Can you add your `.env` especially the `DATABASE_URL` looks like? I assume it's missing the database name there. Make sure to also check the config/packages/tests/ folderand your phpunit.xml in case it overwrites the value.

Comment: done. ty. phpunit.xml.dist is the original file, i dont edit this one.

Comment: In that case check the `phpunit.xml.dist` for an env-entry in the `<php>` section. It should match the database url in your env file.

Comment: That's work !! ty, just add : <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/userDemo" /> in phpunit.xml.dist

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

Documentation explains how to fix your problem pretty well in [Changing Database Settings for Functional Tests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests):

> If you have functional tests, you want them to interact with a real database. Most of the time you want to use a dedicated database connection to make sure not to overwrite data you entered when developing the application and also to be able to clear the database before every test.
>
> To do this, you can override the value of the DATABASE_URL env var in the phpunit.xml.dist to use a diferent database for your tests:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" charset="utf-8" ?>
> <phpunit>
>     <php>
>         <!-- the value is the Doctrine connection string in DSN format -->
>         <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/DB_NAME" />
>     </php>
> </phpunit>
> ```

Comment: Thank you Jakub, but document dont explain how to create database + schema with command line, by example : php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test doesnt work :( (in sf4)

Comment: That wasn't your original question. If you feel something is missing from the documentation create an issue or a pull request in the docs repo: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs